# How do I put the reference after "Theorem" instead of below it?

Tags: beamer, citing

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\cite{}

\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I put the reference after "Theorem" instead of below it?

Thank you!

Comment: In general `\begin{theorem}\cite{}` is poor style, use `\begin{theorem}[{\cite{}}]` I've added an extra set of `{}`'s in case you're using ``\begin{theorem}[{\cite[page~4]{...}}]`

Comment: @daleif Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the syntax `\begin{theorem}\cite{}` in not recommended. Remember that (most) theorem constructions can take an extra title as an optional argument.

```
\begin{theorem}[{\cite{}}]
```

Note that I've already added an extra set of braces, then

```
\begin{theorem}[{\cite[page~4]{...}}]
```

will work, because `\begin{theorem}[\cite[page~4]{...}]` will fail due to how optional arguments looks for `]`.